# Couchbase URL error unauthorized: password required

Tags: nosql, authorization, couchbase

I'm using the UI of Couchbase Community 7.1.1

On the `view` page there is a link next to the results filter:  `?stale=false&inclusive_end=true&connection_timeout=60000`. When I click at the link:

**Expected behavior:** A new tab with the results is opened where I can adjust the URL parameters, like the ordering with `descending=true`

**Actual behavior:** A new tab with the following error message is opened: `{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"password required"}`

I'm on the Administrator account and have full privileges. A password is set for the Administrator account and I can successfully log into this account.

How can I fix the problem with the authorization and the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly query the view port(8092).
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/views/views-querying.html#querying

From ui you can click on “show result” button where it displays the result.